# How to control DropDownMenu position in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, composable

I have a row with a text align at the start and a image align at the end. When I press the image I'm showing a DropdownMenu, but this appear in the start of the row and I want that appear at the end of the row.

I'm trying to use Alignment.centerEnd in Modifier component but is not working.

How can I do that the popup appear at the end of the row?

```
@Composable
fun DropdownDemo(currentItem: CartListItems) {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()) {
        Text(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.TopStart),
            text = currentItem.type,
            color = colorResource(id = R.color.app_grey_dark),
            fontSize = 12.sp)
        Image(painter = painterResource(R.drawable.three_dots),
            contentDescription = "more options button",
            Modifier
                .padding(top = 5.dp, bottom = 5.dp, start = 5.dp)
                .align(Alignment.CenterEnd)
                .width(24.dp)
                .height(6.75.dp)
                .clickable(indication = null,
                    interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                    onClick = {
                        expanded = true
                    }))
        DropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(
                    Color.LightGray
                ).align(Alignment.CenterEnd),
        ) {
            DropdownMenuItem(onClick = { expanded = false }) {
                Text("Delete")
            }
            DropdownMenuItem(onClick = { expanded = false }) {
                Text("Save")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

As [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#dropdownmenu) says:

> A DropdownMenu behaves similarly to a Popup, and will use the position of the parent layout to position itself on screen.

You need to put `DropdownMenu` together with the caller view in a `Box`. In this case `DropdownMenu` will appear under the caller view.

```
var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
Column {
    Text("Some text")
    Box {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.test),
            contentDescription = "more options button",
            modifier = Modifier
                .clickable {
                    expanded = true
                }
        )
        DropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
        ) {
            DropdownMenuItem(onClick = { expanded = false }) {
                Text("Delete")
            }
            DropdownMenuItem(onClick = { expanded = false }) {
                Text("Save")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code snippet will always show the dropdown menu in the left side. Is there any way to get it to show in the center?

Comment: @kc_dev it actually automatically detects the direction, if there is no space available to display on the right side, it will show it on the left side. I'm not sure if the material guidelines thinks displaying centered is a good idea, if you find such information - you can [open](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128) a feature request. So far, the only thing you can adjust is the `offset` - you need to measure the width of the element as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71162398/3585796) and add half that value to the `offset` parameter.

Comment: Note that the menu will always be placed in the top-left corner of the screen for the **Live Preview** inside Android Studio. However the placement is correct on the emulator or a physical device.

Answer (score 3):

> When I press the image I'm showing a DropdownMenu, but this appear in the start of the row and I want that appear at the end of the row.

This is simple to achieve. Use `contentAlignment = Alignment.TopStart` on the parent `Box` of the `DropdownMenu`.

But it's also possible to place the `DropDownMenu` on the touch position by intercepting the touch events using `Modifier.pointerInteropFilter()`.

```
Column(Modifier.padding(12.dp)) {
  var offset = Offset.Zero
  var dropDownExpanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

  Card(
      Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
          .shadow(1.dp, CardDefaults.shape)
          .pointerInteropFilter {
            offset = Offset(it.x, it.y)
            false
          }
          .combinedClickable(onClick = {}, onLongClick = { dropDownExpanded = true })) {
        Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.TopStart) {
          Text(
              "Long press me",
              Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(vertical = 50.dp),
              textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
          Box {
            DropdownMenu(
                expanded = dropDownExpanded,
                offset = DpOffset(pxToDp(offset.x), pxToDp(offset.y)),
                onDismissRequest = { dropDownExpanded = false }) {
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                      text = { Text("Dismiss me") }, onClick = { dropDownExpanded = false })
                }
          }
        }
      }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the [offset parameter of the DropdownMenu()](https://semicolonspace.com/dropdown-menu-jetpack-compose/#menu-position).

```
DropdownMenu(
    offset = DpOffset(x = (-66).dp, y = (-10).dp)
)
```

Change the `x` and `y` values. They accept both positive and negative values.

Comment: This would behave too odd

Comment: Can you explain above the code and values.

Comment: See this guide: https://semicolonspace.com/dropdown-menu-jetpack-compose/

Comment: But why -66 and -10?

Comment: I upvoted because it working for me