# Jetpack Compose - DropdownMenu / Composable is placed outside (the) Box

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am trying to make a custom TopBar for my application and I want to have a `DropdownMenu` displayed in the top right corner of the screen. I have a `Box` that contains a `Row` (with some text and icons) and a `DropdownMenu` which is initially not displayed. When I click on an icon, the `DropdownMenu` is displayed, but outside the `Box`, so not where I intended. The code:

```
@Composable
private fun TopBar {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .border(1.dp, Color.Black)
    ) {
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Ride history",
                maxLines = 1,
                fontSize = 25.sp
            )

            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End
            ) {
                IconButton(
                    onClick = {}) {
                    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Search, contentDescription = null)
                }
                IconButton(
                    onClick = { expanded = !expanded }) {
                    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Sort, contentDescription = null)
                }
                IconButton(
                    onClick = { findNavController().navigate(RideFragmentDirections.actionRideFragmentToSettingsFragment())}) {
                    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Settings, contentDescription = null)
                }
            }
        }
        DropdownMenu(
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.TopEnd),
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }
        ) {
            DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {}) {
                Text(text = "BlaBla")
            }
            DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {}) {
                Text(text = "BlaBla")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I obtain:

[image]

(I put a border around the Box to see its bounds)

After I press the Sort button, the `DropdownMenu` appears, but it is placed outside the `Box`. I want it to be placed in the top right corner, over everything. What am I missing?

**Update**

```
@Composable
private fun TopBar() {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .border(1.dp, Color.Black)
    ) {
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Ride history",
                maxLines = 1,
                fontSize = 25.sp
            )

            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End
            ) {
                IconButton(
                    onClick = {}
                ) {
                    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Search, contentDescription = null)
                }
                IconButton(
                    onClick = { expanded = !expanded }
                ) {
                    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Sort, contentDescription = null)
                }
                IconButton(
                    onClick = {}
                ) {
                    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Settings, contentDescription = null)
                }
            }
        }
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight().align(Alignment.TopEnd),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.TopEnd
        ) {
            DropdownMenu(
                expanded = expanded,
                onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }
            ) {
                DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {}) {
                    Text(text = "BlaBla")
                }
                DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {}) {
                    Text(text = "BlaBla")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This yields:

[image]

Comment: Try placing DropdownMenu inside another Box with contentAlignment = Alignment.TopStart

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DropDownMenu in Compose no align at end of the row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68728375/dropdownmenu-in-compose-no-align-at-end-of-the-row)

Comment: @PhilipDukhov Sort of!  I wrapped `DropdownMenu` with `modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.TopEnd), contentAlignment = Alignment.TopEnd )` but it is not enough. My dropdownMenu is displayed at the end of the row, which is good, but not right at the top of the row but the center of it (the icons are cut in half). I think that might be caused by the `Alignment.CenterVertically` of the `Row`, but I need this modifier.

Comment: @LaC Thanks. Sadly not enough );

Comment: @daniyelp could you update your code and image with the result you've got?

Comment: @PhilipDukhov I just did.

Comment: @daniyelp It will not be placed on top of the row. `DropdownMenu` is part of Material items, and according to [Material guidelines](https://material.io/components/menus#dropdown-menu) should be placed below the element. Right now it's placed in the middle, because you didn't exactly follow my answer: you need to place it in a `Box`  with the button that opens it, in this case it will open under that button.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov I tried it as you said. Surprsingly the DropdownMenu still starts from the center. But I think I'll abandon this and stick to the Material guidlines. Thanks for pointing that out to me.

Answer (score 6):

According to [Material guidelines](https://material.io/components/menus#dropdown-menu) the dropdown menu should be placed below the element.

To get this layout in Compose with `DropdownMenu`, you need to put it in a `Box` with the calling button, like this:

```kotlin
Box {
    IconButton(
        onClick = { expanded = !expanded }
    ) {
        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Sort, contentDescription = null)
    }
    DropdownMenu(
        expanded = expanded,
        onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }
    ) {
        DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {}) {
            Text(text = "BlaBla")
        }
        DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {}) {
            Text(text = "BlaBla")
        }
    }
}
```

Output where `Sort` is the calling button:

[image]

Comment: Look what I have bumped into right now xd: https://www.material.io/components/menus/android#dropdown-menus. `OverFlow Menus`. So this means it's up to me what menu style I choose?

Comment: @daniyelp yes, but at the moment Compose does not implement anything like `OverflowMenu`. You can try to implement it yourself.