# DropdownMenu Padding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In the making of a dropdown menu in compose, I ran across a problem where my DropdownMenu will always fillMaxWidth as given in the modifier.
my goal is to add padding so it will match the content of the screen, however adding padding to the modifier did not work...

```
@Composable
fun PriorityDropDown(
    priority: Priority,
    onPrioritySelected: (Priority) -> Unit
) {

    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val dropDownIconAngle: Float by animateFloatAsState(targetValue = if (expanded) 0f else -90f)

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(MaterialTheme.colors.background)
            .height(PRIORITY_DROPDOWN_HEIGHT)
            .clickable { expanded = true }
            .border(
                width = 1.dp,
                shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface.copy(alpha = ContentAlpha.disabled)
            ),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(PRIORITY_INDICATOR_SIZE)
                .weight(1.5f),
            onDraw = {
                drawCircle(color = priority.color)
            }
        )

        Text(
            text = priority.name,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle2,
            modifier = Modifier.weight(8f)
        )

        IconButton(
            onClick = { expanded = true },
            modifier = Modifier.weight(2f)
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowDropDown,
                contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.drop_down_arrow),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .alpha(ContentAlpha.medium)
                    .rotate(dropDownIconAngle)
            )
        }

        DropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

What it's like without padding:

[image]

What it's like with hardcoding `.fillMaxWidth(fraction = 0.942f)`

[image]

Comment: It isn't clear what you want. Do you want the dropdown menu items and its container to align like you've shown in the second image? If so, it's not working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to control DropDownMenu position in Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68728375/how-to-control-dropdownmenu-position-in-jetpack-compose)

Comment: as I said, the second picture is with hardcoded code, using a fraction. its not a viable solution

Answer (score 13, accepted):

adding
`var rowSize by remember { mutableStateOf(Size.Zero) }`

to the Row modifier adding:

```
.onGloballyPositioned { layoutCoordinates ->
    rowSize = layoutCoordinates.size.toSize()
}
```

Then to the DropDown Modifier:

```
.width(with(LocalDensity.current) { rowSize.width.toDp() })
```

solved the problem