# Pass data from modifier to painter

Tags: android, image, android-jetpack-compose

How to get data from modifier to pass it to painter.
I want to build an address for an image after getting the width of the view in pixels.
How can I do it?

```
Image(
       contentDescription = null,
       modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .onGloballyPositioned { layoutCoordinates ->
                      layoutCoordinates.size.width                  <--- get width in px
                 },

       painter = rememberImagePainter(
                    data = "https://example.com/width_in_px/image.jpg", <--- pass width in px
                    builder = {
                        size(OriginalSize)
                    },
                )
            )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Compose you can pass any data using state variables. In my example I'm using a `Box` to measure size, so you can add image to the view tree only when you know the width. Also I'm using value+setter mutable state syntax to allow smart cast.

```kotlin
val (width, setWidth) = remember { mutableStateOf<Int?>(null) }
Box(
    Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .onSizeChanged { size ->
            setWidth(size.width)
        }
) {
    if (width != null) {
        Image(
            contentDescription = null,
            painter = rememberImagePainter(
                data = "https://example.com/${width}/image.jpg",
                builder = {
                    size(OriginalSize)
                },
            ),
            modifier = Modifier
                .matchParentSize()
        )
    }
}
```