# Unresolved reference: ExposedDropdownMenuBox in Compose for Desktop

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

I need to implement a drop down menu for Windows App which is based on [Compose for Desktop](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/compose-mpp/)
For that I am trying to use `ExposedDropdownMenuBox`

But I am getting error:

> Unresolved reference: ExposedDropdownMenuBox

Following is the code:

```
ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
    expanded = expanded,
    onExpandedChange = {
        expanded = !expanded
    }
) {
    // TextFeild implementation
}
```

And the file `build.gradle.kts` contains following:

```
import org.jetbrains.compose.compose
import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.10"
    id("org.jetbrains.compose") version "1.1.1"
}

group = "com.op.bgmi"
version = "1.0"

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
}

dependencies {
    implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
}

compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"
        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
            packageName = "App"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something, please advice.
What is the correct approach to have drop down menu box in Compose for Desktop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ExposedDropdownMenuBox` is currently not available for Desktop.

You can check the location of the item in the AndroidX repository: it is [located](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/compose/material/material/src/androidMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/ExposedDropdownMenu.kt) in `androidMain` folder, which makes it only available for the Android platform. It uses some Android-specific APIs under the hood, which makes it impossible to use from the desktop.

Perhaps it will be rewritten and made cross-platform before the `Experimental` annotation is removed, or there will be a separate implementation for Desktop in the future. You can follow updates [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/issues/1673).

For now, you can use `DropdownMenu` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68728525/3585796).