# Use of DropdownMenu with Jetpack Compose (Material)

Tags: drop-down-menu, android-jetpack-compose

I decided to use an `OutlinedTextField` and `DropdownMenu` so the user can fill an amount and select a currency.

This looks pretty nice in the preview, but when this code is being run on the device (virtual or physical) the `DropdownMenu` is being squeezed on the right, and therefore, the dropdown menu isn't actionable anymore.

````
@Composable
fun Money() {
    Row() {
        Amount()
        Currency()
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun Currency() {

    var mExpanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val mCurrencies = listOf("USD", "CHF", "EUR", "MAD") //, "Hyderabad", "Bengaluru", "PUNE")

    var mSelectedText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    var mTextFieldSize by remember { mutableStateOf(Size.Zero) }

    val icon = if (mExpanded)
        Icons.Filled.KeyboardArrowUp
    else
        Icons.Filled.KeyboardArrowDown

    OutlinedTextField(
        value = mSelectedText,
        onValueChange = { mSelectedText = it },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                // This value is used to assign to
                // the DropDown the same width
                mTextFieldSize = coordinates.size.toSize()
            },
        label = { Text("Currency") },
        trailingIcon = {
            Icon(icon, "contentDescription",
                Modifier.clickable { mExpanded = !mExpanded })
        }
    )

    DropdownMenu(
        expanded = mExpanded,
        onDismissRequest = { mExpanded = false },
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(with(LocalDensity.current) { mTextFieldSize.width.toDp() })
    ) {
        mCurrencies.forEach { label ->
            DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                mSelectedText = label
                mExpanded = false
            }) {
                Text(text = label)
            }
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun Amount() {
    var amount by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    OutlinedTextField(
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
        value = amount,
        onValueChange = { amount = it },
        label = { Text(text = "Amount") },
        singleLine = true,
        trailingIcon = {
            if (amount.isNotBlank())
                IconButton(onClick = { amount = "" }) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Filled.Clear,
                        contentDescription = ""
                    )
                }
        }
    )
}```
````

Comment: Have you check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68728525/3585796)? wrap `OutlinedTextField` with `DropdownMenu` in a `Box`. In preview it's a `Box` by default on top of the view, but in your real core you have a `Column` which makes a different layout